# The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects when updating a record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am getting the error "**The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.**" when updating the ***permission*** record with **UserRoles** navigation.

```
var permission = _permissionService.GetPermissionRecordBySystemName(permissionSystemName);
if (permission != null) 
{
    var userRole = _userService.GetUserRoleById(roleId); 
    if (permission.UserRoles.Contains(userRole))
    {
        permission.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);
    }
    else
    {
        permission.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
    }
    _permissionService.Update(permission); // Error at this line
}
```

I have used UnityContainer and repository pattern.

I have used EntityFramework(Code First). Following is the code of "**PermissionRecord**" class

```
public class PermissionRecord : BaseEntity
{
    private ICollection<UserRole> _userRoles;    

    public string Name { get; set; }    

    public string SystemName { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles
    {
        get => _userRoles ?? (_userRoles = new List<UserRole>());
        protected set => _userRoles = value;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please refer: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699897/entity-framework-the-relationship-between-the-two-objects-cannot-be-defined-be) and [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693843/entity-framework-multiple-object-contexts/5695009#5695009)

Comment: @Shawn Xiao Thank you, I have already referred these links. The problem occurred because of Unity, I just removed it and used Autofac. Its working now.